# password aging policy, the passwd command and /etc/shadow

Tags: solaris, password

I came across this phrase in the link below
http://brandonhutchinson.com/wiki/Solaris_Password_Policy

> /usr/bin/passwd is used to modify password aging on existing accounts.
>   **passwd does not update the last password change field (field 3) in /etc/shadow, so passwords could expire immediately after running it.**

What has the 3rd field in `/etc/shadow` got to do with the expiry of password?  I tried to force expire a user account and the 3rd field did change.

```
sghk1> cat /etc/shadow | grep test
test:$1$khA8kfQ7$B1lHXn5N8h5CvKx0WnibV.:16665:7:420::::
sghk1> passwd -f test
passwd: password information changed for test
sghk1> passwd -s test
test      PS    00/00/00     7   420
sghk1> cat /etc/shadow | grep test
test:$1$khA8kfQ7$B1lHXn5N8h5CvKx0WnibV.:0:7:420::::
```

From 16665 to 0.

So what does the author mean?

Also, for existing users, how do we make policies/configurations in /etc/default/passwd take place on existing accounts?

Comment: Did you run your experiment on Solaris or on Linux (you used multiple OS tags, which makes me wonder)? I don't know if Solaris and Linux behave in the same way.

Comment: sorry, I am running solaris